# Use views to produce list of terms with descriptions

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a Tags taxonomy which includes a couple of terms with *descriptions*.

Tags are rendered in a simple inline list under the content, and this is fine for most of them.

But some terms are acting as flags, e.g. "needs update", "stub". For these, just being listed at the bottom is not enough.

I would like to make a view block that lists **all terms that have descriptions** (and not ones that don't). I plan to then stick this at the top of the Content section and use a contextual filter so that if a page is tagged "needs update" you get a warning at the top of the page explaining what this tag means. Just like wikipedia does for "This page is a *stub* - it needs more info...".

Problem: views 3 (on Drupal 7) does not appear to be able to add term:description as a filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A easy workaround could be to attach a regular text-field to the terms, instead of using the hardcoded description.

**Update:** After taking a quick peek in the code, it does look like filtering on descriptions are not supported. This could just be a simple oversight.
There's an [issue here](http://drupal.org/node/1012584), which claims this functionality has been added. I can't seem to find it, so I attached a new patch and reopened the issue.

**Update 2:** Dereine has commited my patch to D7. You should now be able to filter on term descriptions with the dev version.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently doing it by adding another field to Terms, a boolean "Is a flag" field, which *does* appear in the filter list. Just seems odd you can't filter on the description field; thought I must be being daft!